# Prove $(a \times b) = 0$ implies $\{ a,b \} $ is linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a,b$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. If $(a \times b) = 0 $, how can we use the definition of cross product to prove that $\{ a,b \}$ is linearly dependent?

Comment: $a\times b$ is by definition the area of the praralelogramm defined by $a$ and $b$.

Comment: $\vec{a}\times \vec{b} = 0$ implies that they are parallel, ie, $ \vec{a} = k\vec{b}$

Comment: Why haven't you grouped this question with the previous question of the same exercise you asked very shortly before ? At least, you should have mentionned it ?

Answer (score 2):

Using the definition with the determinant, the reason becomes more apparent : let $B$ be the canonical basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$, then $x\to det_B(a,b,x)$ is a linear form by definition of the determinant, and so by Riesz's theorem, there exists a unique vector, call it $a\times b$  (it's the actual definition of cross product), such that for all $x$, $det_B(a,b,x) = \langle a\times b, x\rangle$. Now if $a\times b= 0$, then it must mean that for all $x$, $det_B(a,b,x)= 0$, hence for all $x$, $(a,b,x)$ is linearly dependent.

But if $(a,b)$ were independent, then the incomplete basis theorem would give us a vector $c$ such that $(a,b,c)$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$, and thus linearly independent.

Thus $(a,b)$ is linearly dependent

Answer (score 1):

Since $\overrightarrow a \times \overrightarrow b= |\overrightarrow a||\overrightarrow b| \sin \theta$ , where $\theta$ is angle between $\overrightarrow a$ and $\overrightarrow b$.

$\overrightarrow a \times \overrightarrow b= |\overrightarrow a||\overrightarrow b| \sin \theta = 0 \implies \theta =0 \implies \overrightarrow a \parallel \overrightarrow b$

Therefore we can write $\overrightarrow a = k \cdot \overrightarrow b ~; ~k \in \mathbb{R} $ and $k \neq 0$

$$\overrightarrow a - k\overrightarrow b=0  \implies ~\text{$\overrightarrow a$ and $\overrightarrow b$ are linearly dependent}$$

**Note:** It is not mentioned that $\overrightarrow a$ and $\overrightarrow b$ are non zero. Hence that's an ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

One can also use the identity: $u\wedge(v\wedge w)=(u\cdot w)\,v-(u\cdot v)\,w$

$a\wedge(a\wedge b)=0\iff (a\cdot b)\,a-(a\cdot a)\,b=0$

If $a=0$ then $a,b$ are trivially linearly dependent.

If $a\neq 0$ then $\displaystyle b=\frac{(a\cdot b)}{(a\cdot a)}\,a$